# How many hours do you bill per week? per day?

Tags: freelance-websites, time-tracking

I'm trying to figure out equivalent hourly rate for freelancer job comparing to office job.
As freelancer you usually bill only real working hours(without breaks).

So having full load with hourly job and using odesk/elance tracker or something similar, how many hours do you bill in average per week? per day?
Update:
I'm trying to figure out hourly rate equivalent for a long term freelance job. 
For instance if I get Xk$ per month for 40h/week, then what should be freelance hourly rate for this job, considering that in freelance breaks are not paid.

Answer (score 3):

The worst possible thing you can do as a freelance is to price yourself on an hourly basis. Doing so forces you to itemize innumerable items on invoices, and it requires that you track time spent on 5 minute phone calls and what have you. The inevitable outcome is getting micro-managed into oblivion by fussy clients -- clients which, by the way, you simply do not want.

Successful freelances think in terms of value, and price themselves accordingly.

They charge per day, per week, per feature, or even -- when things are well-scoped and obviously not going to turn into a rabbit hole of changes and add-ons and what have you -- per project. Anything works, as long as it's not hourly.

Identify what upside your prospect is going to have by hiring you to do the job. Then get a sense of how much your prospect is willing to pay to get this upside. Convince him that you will deliver this upside. And start the negotiation from there, with the full understanding that you're not here to bill by the hour -- you're here to deliver this upside, and this upside is reachable with X days or weeks of efforts.

What you're charging for is being focused on this one particular client. And as a freelance, it is a given for all (good) clients that you've administrative overhead: you need to worry about your pipeline, you need to answer emergency calls and emails from other clients, and so forth.

Once this ticks, it doesn't matter if you're actually working 6 hour days when charging daily, or 4 days per week when charging weekly. It doesn't matter because you're not delivering time; you're delivering *value*.

Comment: It might be an overstatement to say "don't use hourly". Even though you don't track your work minute-by-minute, having a fixed hourly rate helps you calculate how much you're going to charge on different projects: be that a part-time you're going to charge weekly, a biweekly full-time or a one-week bug-fix project.

Answer (score 1):

We usually use trackers of all kinds to track actual work we spent on some project. And we report those hours. I also like to give clients insight to the tracker so he can see that I am reporting time properly. My clients rarely check that, but I give them access anyway.

So you will report time you actually spent on some project/task. Now, if you are in the estimation phase and the client wants you to work full-time on some project, then I would not estimate more than 6 productive hours a day. If I try to work 8 productive hours a day, it will take like 11 hours of real time. So just calculate 6 per day, 30/36 per week.

In case of fixed tasks, I do not report how much time I spent.

Comment: glad to know I'm not stupid by not being able to get 8 productive hours per day. that was driving me nuts.